# Eclipse giving error for onClickListener which disagrees with documentation

Tags: android, onclick

code:

```
import java.util.UUID;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainDrawingActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawing);


    LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
    drawObj = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
    currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0); 
    currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed)); 
    smallBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    mediumBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    largeBrush = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.large_size);
    drawBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.draw_btn);
    drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

//declare variables down here because that's just where they are, okay?
private float smallBrush, mediumBrush, largeBrush;
private DrawingView drawObj; 
private ImageButton currPaint, drawBtn; 

public void onClick(View view, int i){
    if (view.getId()==R.id.draw_btn){
        final Dialog brushDialog = new Dialog(this);
        brushDialog.setTitle("Brush size: ");
        brushDialog.setContentView(R.layout.brush_layout);

        ImageButton smallBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.small_brush);
        ImageButton mediumBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium_brush);
        ImageButton largeBtn = (ImageButton)brushDialog.findViewById(R.id.large_brush);
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                drawObj.setNewSize(smallBrush);
                drawObj.setLastSize(smallBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        mediumBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                drawObj.setNewSize(mediumBrush);
                drawObj.setLastSize(mediumBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        smallBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                drawObj.setNewSize(largeBrush);
                drawObj.setLastSize(largeBrush);
                brushDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        brushDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Error on public class declaration:

```
The type MainDrawingActivity must implement the inherited abstract method 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)
```

Error on `drawBtn.setOnClickListener(this);` :

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable
 for the arguments (MainDrawingActivity)
```

Errors on `setOnClickListener(new onClickListener` :

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable
 for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})
```

This is in contrast to the Android documentation which defines `onClick()` as taking a `View` for its parameters, not a `DialogInterface` and an integer.

Someone please help me make sense of this! Is my IDE out of date or am I simply being an idiot somewhere? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing the OnClickListener() from DialogInterface. You should be implementing the OnClickListener() from the View interface.